# the parent class and package are reported by Test results analyzer Jenkins plugin as passed even though if they are only composed by skipped testcases

Tags: jenkins, junit, report, analyzer

The parent class and package are reported by Test results analyzer Jenkins plugin as passed even though if they are only composed by skipped testcases

I've got the problem on my project with this kind of JUnit result configuration :

```
...
<testsuite name="7-_Test_Business" tests="0" skipped="2" errors="0" failures="0" time="0.012">
<testcase time="0" classname="7-_Test_Business.7-1_OXE" name="7-1-1-1a_-_Initialize_SIP_session">
<skipped/>
</testcase>
<testcase time="0" classname="7-_Test_Business.7-2_CUCM" name="7-2-1-6b_-_Finalize_SIP_session">
<skipped/>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
...
```

I would like to know if someone have found a solution to share a status SKIPPED to a testsuite composed by only skipped testcase?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that fixed bug [JENKINS-12567](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-12567) decided to treat skip test similar to success:

> When there are skipped tests but no failures, the build should be marked SUCCESS

Comment: To my mind, it would be more logical that if there are only skipped tests (without any failure tests) in a testsuite, the status of the testsuite is skipped too.

Comment: The problem with the actual behavior is that if few testsuites are success even thought there are only composed of skipped, you cannot quickly detect the evolution if one of them contain a success. To my mind it's a lack of information given to users of this plugin

Comment: I would prefer the following behavior : 
- if a test suite is composed only of success and skipped test then its status must be success
- if a test suite is composed of at least one test in error then its status must be error
- if a test suite is composed of only skipped tests then its status must be skipped

Comment: @npenna22 There's no such status, do you want to open issue to add SKIPPED result status?  see http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Result.html